# Generic object detections

Tags: python, object-detection, detection, unsupervised-learning

I am recently working on detection of foreign object which present along with raw material. Normally, I had some experience based on supervised object detectors such as yolov, detectron that learns with custom annotation by training. These annotations helps those object detector for learn the feature of object the present in the training images and it can inference regarding to those feature.

I our case, there are some unknown object passes through the conveyor. we don't know which type of foreign object will passes along with the conveyor that carries the raw material. Each and every foreign object have unique features. so i try to use some unsupervised object detection methods which available in github. I also tried some weakly supervised detection. But they are keep failing in our case.

Is there any detection technique or pretrained model to detect unique featured object or generic object that present in image? If possible, please guide me by providing any algorithm or technique suitable for this case. Thanks in advance.

For generic object proposal - referred [link](https://github.com/mmaaz60/mvits_for_class_agnostic_od)

For weakly supervised - referred [link](https://github.com/idilesenzulfikar/UNOVOST)

Comment: Please share what models / libraries you've tried and exact errors you have gotten. Asking for external, alternative resources is considered off-topic as per [help]

Comment: I had attached the reference link that i tried. these two repos which work on generic manner for object detection. I am not expecting for the code. I need some idealogy and suggestions with respect to my problem base.